# Change text of edit text on button click inside custom adapter

Tags: android

How to change text in edit text which is embedded in a list view. i want to the change the text's value on button click

```
holder.txtQty.setTag(position);
    holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String val = holder.txtQty.getText().toString();
            Float f = new Float(val);
            f = f + 1;
            holder.txtQty.setText(f.toString().replace(".0", "").trim());
        }
    });
```

but on this only the first and last rows edit text change . i need the corresponding edit text to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get the position in the list of the text you wish to change, write a public method to replace the content at that position and then notify the custom adapter that the data set has changed.

For example:

```
public void replaceItemAt(int position, String newText)
{
    //Replace the item in the array list
    this.textfieldarraylist.set(position, newText);
    //Let the custom adapter know it needs to refresh the view
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change text of edittext then you can store it in an arraylist. suppose if 3rd element is clicked then you can just get(position) from arraylist and then set it. Initially set all values with default. so in this way you can set and finally get text from your arraylist.
every time when edittext text will change then get the position and then save it to your arraylist...